# When using the destroy method "Couldn't find user with id" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I'm making a CRUD app, and everything works except destroy. When I click on a delete button when I'm in the edit page, I get the following error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TravelersController#show, Couldn't find Traveler with 'id'=14, Extracted source (around line #22):

```
def show
    @traveler = Traveler.find(params[:id])
end
```

But if I go back to my list of users, the application does delete that user even though I'm getting that error.

Here is my controller code:

```
  def show
    @traveler = Traveler.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    Traveler.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to traveler_path
  end
```

And my edit page:

```
   <%= form_for @traveler do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :age %>
      <%= f.number_field :age %></br>

      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to "DELETE", traveler_path(@traveler), :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: do you have ///= require jquery_ujs in your application.js ? --- also when you click delete on the button, in your log file, do you see an entry that says "Started DELETE "/travelers/32"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because when you destroy the traveler, you then redirect to `traveler_path`, which is a `show` action for **the traveler you just deleted**. It's trying to load that traveller and fails.

To fix this, just change it to redirect somewhere else - for example, a travelers index path.